# Why is "para" not used consistently?

Tags: meaning

I've been told that the prefix "para" means "against".

- Parachute (against falling)
- Paramilitary (against military)
- Paraply/umbrella (against raining)

But, other words does not make much sense to me:

- Paramedic (against medicine?)
- Paraglider (against gliding?)

Pardon my Ausberger, but why isn't "para" used consistently?

Comment: @OP: you may want to consider switching your question to "Why does *para* have multiple meanings?" or something along those lines so it might be saved.

Comment: Isn't paramilitary something more along the lines like 'similar/in imitation to military', i.e., a SWAT team is professionally trained, highly equipped, have ranks, have uniforms, have a strict and defined chain of command, but are not military, therefore are a paramilitary force? -- This doesn't answer your question, but I wouldn't consider the para prefix in paramilitary to mean 'against'

Comment: Here is what I believe is the real answer: The words *parachute, parasol,* and *paraply* (Fr. *parapluie*) come directly from French, where *para-* appears to have changed its meaning to *against*. In the words *paramilitary, paramedic,* and *paraglider,* the prefix *para-* retains its original Latin meaning of *beside.*

Comment: Let me clarify the above answer. The prefix *para-* meaning beside is [Greek](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=para-), and the prefix *para-* meaning *against* is [French,](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pare&allowed_in_frame=0) stemming from the Latin word *parare* (to make ready) unrelated to the Greek *para-*. No shift of meaning, just a coincidence.

Comment: @PeterShor So explain "parapsychology" - which for some reason means "psychology of ghosts" ? ;)