# Can “paraxial” mean “axis-parallel”?

Tags: meaning, mathematics, technical

The Wiktionary lists under the meanings of *[paraxial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paraxial):*

> 3. (mathematics) Parallel to one or more axes of the coordinate system
>           ***paraxial*** rectangle

The respective information was [added without any reference](http://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=paraxial&diff=21388477&oldid=21119832) and given the following reasons I am skeptical about it.

- *Para* means *close to* and similar, not *parallel,* which is for example reflected in another meaning:

  > 2. (physics) Near an optical axis
  >       ***paraxial*** radiation

  On the other hand, I am aware that the actual use of a word may depart from its etymology.
- Other dictionaries do not report *paraxial* meaning *axis-parallel,* but this may be due to the term being rather rare and technical (some dictionaries don’t contain *paraxial* at all).

My question thus is: **Is *paraxial* actually used in the meaning of *axis-parallel* by some communities?** Be aware that in many contexts, *close to the axis* may imply *axis-parallel* or *almost axis-parallel.* Relatedly, I am interested in uses of *paraxial* for something that is parallel but not close to an axis.

Comment: Googling *"paraxial rectangle"* returns a few, but not many, sites which use it for *"axis-parallel rectangle"*, including some technical papers by German speakers, and some technical papers in computer science. I would guess there must be a similar word in German that is being translated this way (and computer scientists tend to form portmanteau words).

Comment: The [paraxial mesoderm](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraxial_mesoderm) is worth considering, as its etymology seems self-evident (*parallel to the axis of the embryo*), but since I have no authority to back me up on that, I'll have to leave this as a comment rather than answer. Also PM may be used as a fixed phrase, as opposed to "paraxial" serving as a generic adjective in embryology.

Comment: @PeterShor: The results for `"paraxial rectangle"` seem to be dominated by Wiktionary clones and German resources. As for the latter: A popular German–English online dictionary [lists *paraxial* as a translation of *achsenparallel*](http://dict.leo.org/ende/?lp=ende&search=paraxial), with the latter literally meaning *axis-parallel,* but this may have very-well be originated from said Wiktionary entry and would not be the first mistake they made.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I easily find several citations, all from German software developers:

- > …let the coordinates of two paraxial rectangles in a cartesian coordinate system be given…

  — [The Computer—My Life](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ro5JOskbChAC&pg=PA211)
- > …which form the endpoints of the diagonal of a paraxial rectangle…

  — [Programming Smalltalk](https://books.google.com/books?id=RAloBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA282)
- > …an oriented rectangle with anchor point (0, 0) width 100, height 10, and up vector (0, -1) is a paraxial rectangle with upper left corner (0, -10) and lower right corner (100, 0).

  — [YWorks: OrientedRectangle](http://docs.yworks.com/yfiles/doc/api/y/geom/OrientedRectangle.html)

It seems they have ported this word to English.

Answer (score 0):

M-W Unabridged defines *paraxial* as

> relating to or being the space in the immediate neighborhood of the
>   optical axis of a lens or mirror

One can *approximate* light rays in such a region as being parallel; the *[paraxial approximation](http://audioroundtable.com/misc/Paraxial_Approximation_Explained.pdf)* is used to simplify calculations by modeling most of the propagation to be in a particular direction, to within a particular tolerance.

So *paraxial* would not be objectionable in the usage you're looking for, meaning "parallel to within a useful approximation;" however, you probably shouldn't use it to *mean* "axis-parallel."

Comment: While it is not explicitly mentioned in the file you linked, the [paraxial approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraxial_approximation) does require rays to be close to the axis as well (though through the approach taken here, it’s rather that the axis is defined such that it is close to the rays, see page 5).

Answer (score -4):

*para-* (prefix)

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/para-):

> From Ancient Greek παρά (*pará*, “beside; next to, near, from; against, contrary to”).
>    1. above, beyond
>    2. beside, near, alongside
>    3. abnormal, incorrect
>    4. resembling
>    5. (chemistry) In isomeric benzene derivatives, having the two substituents in opposite positions (compare ortho- and meta-.)

ODO on [para-](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/para-):

> **1** Beside; adjacent to:
>   *parataxis*
>   *parathyroid*

See also: [Why is “para” not used consistently? [closed]](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/54673/14666)

However, in the OP's examples, *parallel to* and *near* are not contradictory or even much different. Nearly all words in all domains with the prefix *para-* have a broad sense of peripherality.

ODO on [paraxial](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/paraxial):

> Anatomy & Zoology
>   Situated alongside, or on each side of, an axis, especially the central axis of the body.

Note the "**alongside, or on each side of, an axis**" above.

Comment: I fail to see how this addresses my question. I know that *parallel* and *near* are not contradictary and, moreover, *near* often implies *parallel,* but this does not mean that *parallel* implies *near* or that *near* means *parallel.*

Comment: It doesn't have to. The instant question is whether anyone uses the para prefix to mean parallel to, right?

Comment: It’s rather specific to the combination of *para* and *axial,* but I do not even see the generalised variant of the question answered due to the above reasons.

Comment: If you are looking to find a relation between *para-* and "parallel," as it apparently is the case -- the answer is not far to seek either: *parallel:* "1540s, from Middle French *parallèle* (16c.) and directly from Latin *parallelus*, from Greek *parallelos* "parallel," from *para allelois* "beside one another," from *para-* "beside" (see para- (1)) + *allelois* "each other," from *allos* "other" (see *alias* (adv.))." (etymonline) HTH :)

Comment: I am aware of this relation. But that’s just another example of a word departing from its etymology, as *beside one another* and *parallel* are not the same thing. The question is whether something similar also happened to or is happening to *paraxial.*

Comment: Good job, @Kris. Both of the questions the OP asked he also answered within his own question. 1) *Paraxial* is **defined** as parallel to an axis. Therefore it means (at least in some contexts) parallel to an axis. 2) *Paraxial* is listed in the dictionary (a descriptive tool) as parallel to the axis, demonstrating that it is used in some communities as axis-parallel. For a line to **remain** close to the axis, it must be parallel to the axis.

Comment: @ScotM: 0) Where did I ask two questions? 1) Who defined *paraxial* such? Do you have a source. 2) Dictionaries, in particular such that everybody can edit tend to be wrong from time to time. I edited my question to make more clear that I am doubting this particular entry.